# Why is asynchronous in an http server needed?

Tags: c, http, asynchronous

I know that modern web servers handle connections asynchronously, but I can't figure out where this asynchrony is required.

I want to understand this with an example written in C. We are writing a simple http web server. Set up a listening socket:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


int main() {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int enable = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(enable)) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    char *address = "127.0.0.1";

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);

    if (inet_aton(address, &addr.sin_addr) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    listen(sock, 10);

    ...
}
```

And then we accept new connections, either starting a child process for each connection, or processing them in one process, or creating several child processes in advance and passing the processing to them - this is not important now.

The interesting thing is that asynchronous code, as far as I know, is needed in order not to block the execution of the main program if I/O is expected. But where in our case will this very expectation be?

I have only one assumption: when we have already accepted the connection and received the client socket, it is possible that due to the slow connection, the user will take a long time to send the request, and our server will take a long time to send the response. But will this really be the case? And if so, how can we use the C language to check the read and write availability of a socket, and at the same time not block the main thread of execution while waiting for a read or write?

Comment: The browser downloads a html page. There are 10 images on this page. If you work synchronously you have to fully download each image and then start with next. With async you can send requests for all 10 images and continue to download them in parallel. Some images may come from different web servers.

Comment: In general a server is an entity that is supposed to serve multiple clients *simultaneously*. You really don't want Google to put your search query in a queue till it is finished the other zillion queries from other users.

Comment: @i486 Your explanation is more about multithreaded client, not server.

Comment: polling can be inefficient.  Client keeps asking, "are you  done, " are you done, etc." Async, the provider tells you when it is done.

Answer (score 3):

> I have only one assumption: when we have already accepted the connection and received the client socket, it is possible that due to the slow connection, the user will take a long time to send the request, and our server will take a long time to send the response. But will this really be the case?

Yes. Imagine your user downloads a big program (100MB) over a dial-up connection (5.6 kB/second). Remember that your server can't send data faster than the client can receive it. Now, nobody else can access your server for 5 hours.

If you create a child process or a thread for each connection, now they can, but having lots of processes creates its own performance problems, and having lots of threads creates more bugs. Still, there are very popular web servers that use these things, like Apache. They are good enough. Other web servers like nginx use asynchronous I/O. They are more complicated, but they can also handle 100000 connections at once - which Apache can't.

> And if so, how can we use the C language to check the read and write availability of a socket, and at the same time not block the main thread of execution while waiting for a read or write?

On Linux, you are looking for the functions `select`, `poll`, or `epoll`. On Windows, you are looking for "overlapped I/O".